# Join query in Mysql of two tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have two tables :

`ad ( id(int) , userid(int) )` : table to store advertisement which have a user column
`adcat ( adid(int) , catid(int) )` : table to store the category id (catid) of each ad (adid)

now all I want is to get the number of ads of a specific category published by a specific user

example : all the ads of catid = 1 and with userid = 725

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ads_total
  FROM ad a JOIN
       adcat c ON a.id = c.adid
 WHERE c.catid = 1 AND
       a.userid = 725
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b89b/2)**

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM ad 
LEFT JOIN adcat 
ON adcat.adid = ad.id
WHERE adcat.catid = 1 AND ad.userid = 725
```

Comment: thank you it works to get the ads, and it's easy to get the number using this query when we add COUNT

Answer (score 1):

you need to join the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM ad INNER JOIN adcat ON adid=id WHERE catid=1 and userid=725;
```

Comment: Thank you it works to get the ads, we can add COUNT to get the number

Comment: sure. just do ```COUNT(*)``` instead of ```*```